# Associate Multiple Products to Activity

Tags: product, activity

We have a unique use case where the our partners would like to associate an Activity to multiple products. I cannot create a junction object because it looks like I cannot have another master (Junction)- detail (Product2) relationship on Product. A lookup will not suffice since they want to associate multiple products to an activity/call.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think junction object is your only option off the top of my head. croprey noted that you can't make Task/Event be the parent of any object which only leaves you with heavier customization. To do this, I think you'd be creating a custom object that would duplicate the records in Task/Event so you can utilize lookups/junction objects. It's not a great option and would get messy quick.

Can you take this a step back? What's the goal in associating multiple products to events/Tasks? Why on the event/task? Is there another custom object you can create that would make more sense to have products attached to it? Can they associate these events/tasks to a different object that would then have a list of the products they'd want? I would push back on why they think they need to do this and what the point of an activity is.

The activity object is generally more rigid which makes sense if you consider what the object is and what it's supposed to be used for (Calendar, to-do, notifications, etc).

Comment: ?? Can Task/Event be the parent of any lookup field?  I don't think junctions can work at all with Task/Event as parent of some object

Comment: Thanks for that. I edited it to reflect the less than ideal situation of building something like that out on activity object.

Comment: Thanks Kris - This is something i'm struggling with because they utilize the task/activity object to capture their phone calls. In this case a phone call with respect to some product.

Comment: I totally understand that. In reality, what are they trying to capture? Engagement calls? Selling? Support on products? Is capturing just one product on the phone call "good enough" or can they create their phone calls in a custom object instead of utilizing tasks. I think the one that makes the most sense is to have you're own object for whatever these phone calls are about instead of being within Tasks.